# Play Games Services for Web - Turn based Game - Creating and Joining room in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web, google-play-games

I created a Simple Web Board game, where each user takes a turn and make their move.

I am now trying to integrate Google Game Play Services to connect 2 friends and let them compete.

With reference to https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/turnBasedMatches#methods

While creating a match, I am to pass `invitedPlayerIds`, which will be the player ID of my friend. But how will I get the ID of the friend, who is logged into his own device?

I was checking this Rooms API @ https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/rooms

Seems most methods are only for Internal use. We can't create, list and join rooms.

Please advice me on how to proceed?

Edit 1: I can write a custom web service to exchange the Player IDs between the players. But I really dont want to do that and it adds more complexity. I believe, this could be done with the GPS itself somehow. But dont know how!

Edit 2:
I tried adding the mail ID of the player in `invitedPlayerIds` field of `https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/turnbasedmatches/create` request body.

But it says `Invalid playerId with value gethugames2020@gmail.com`

Another way would be showing their own cryptic player IDs (like "g04345703229741133710") to the users, Let them communicate the ID via other means (SMS, WhatsApp) and ask them to manually type it into the game.

My Development work is @ http://www.gethugames.in/tic-tac-toe-extended/
You can click the badge at the bottom to see the Achievements API (After logging in)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the Google Play games services, your game needs to implement user sign-in to authenticate your player's identity with the Google Play Games services. If the user is not authenticated, game will encounter errors when making calls to the Google Play games services APIs.

To get the current signed in player ID, if available. Use  ['getCurrentPlayerID'](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Players)

You may check the Quality Checklist for Google Play Games Services: https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist#improving_the_sign_in_experience_for_games

Comment: I implemented the Sign In procedure and also integrated the Achievements API.
I am now stuck with how to pass one user's ID to the other to create a Match.